# how to access Dictionary data within an Arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I am creating Dictionary and an ArrayList such as this.

```
Dictionary testDict, testDict2 = null;
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

testDict.put ("key1", dataVar1);
testDict.put ("key2", dataVar2);
testDict2.put ("key1", dataVar1);
testDict2.put ("key2", dataVar2);

al.add(testDict);
al.add(testDict2);
```

now my issue here is, how can I access the data within the dictionaries? Like for example how would I retrieve key1 from testDict using al?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question; you get the appropriate list entry and access the dictionary like you would normally. Or iterate through the list, checking each dictionary for the key.

Comment: im not sure what youre trying to do, but from the Dictionary javadocs:`NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.`. I think maybe you should use HashMaps instead, and if you want to retrieve multiple values with the same key, you could probably use a new HashMap with the putAll method ... just a guess

Comment: sorry I know it sounds like a really beginner type question. I'm working on a board type game where we have layers on top of layers. Each layer is a dictionary and the board itself is the arraylist. There was no immediate way to access data immediately from the arraylist that I knew of. I hope this answers some questions.

Comment: thanks jambriz, looking into HashMaps then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) all Dictionary objects (note that e.g. Hashtable is one of them) have a method `Object get(Object key)` to access it's elements. In your example you could access the value of the entry `key1` in `textDict` like that:

```
// first access testDict at index 0 in the ArrayList al 
// and then it's element with key "key1"
al.get(0).get("key1");
```

Note, that you nowhere initialize your Dictionary objects and that the `Dictionary` class is abstract. So you could for example use a `Hashtable` (or if you don't need synchronized access use a faster `HashMap` instead) for your purpose like this:

```
testDict = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

And make sure to use the correct generic types (the second one has to be the type that your `dataVar`s have)

Comment: thank you, your answer gave me both the answer I needed, and also gave me a better route to take.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
al.get(0).get("key1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `testDict` is at position 0 (first element of your `ArrayList`) you can retrieve it with `get(0).`.

Example:

```
Dictionary firstDict = (Dictionary) al.get(0);
Object key1Data = firstDict.get("key1");
```

Ps: Generics can greatly improve your code if you are allowed to use it.

Another point is... Why `Dictionary` and not [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: I have not actually coded in java for a while. Thanks to awesome members like yourself I am learning that this is not the ideal way to do it. Map it is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why'd you want keep your dictionaries like that, but you can simply loop over your dictionaries.

```
public Data getData(String key) {
    for(Dictionary dict : al) {
        Data result = dict.get(key);
        if(result != null)
            return result;
        }
    return null;
}
```