# Which is the proper way to work with complex types (lists and objects) in Jaspersoft?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, mongodb-query, jaspersoft-studio

Please consider a MongoDB collection with the following document:

```
"_id": "clientsInfo"
"data": {
    "clientsList" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Mike",
            "country" : "USA"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

After setting the DataSet and defining the Query like this...

```
{
    collectionName:'projectA',
    findQuery: {
        '_id':'clientsInfo',
    },
    findFields: {
        '_id':0,
        'data.clientsList':1
    },
}
```

...I am able to display the first item of the fetched array (`java.util.List` type) in JasperSoft Studio inside a Text Field using the following expression:

```
$F{data.clientsList}.get(0)
```

But, considering that I would like to exhibit the whole data in a Name/Country Table...

**Question1**: How could I access any of the dictionary fields? Trying [get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607562/how-to-access-dictionary-data-within-an-arraylist-in-java) I obtain `The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object.` error. However, knowing that the object is an instance of `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject` it should have that method inherited (See [doc](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html)).

I have also tried to cast object to `org.json.JSONObject` but then I get `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: (JSONObject)$F{data.clientsList}.get(0)` error.

**Question2**: Let's suppose we have already solved first question... How can I iterate the list to access not only the first item but all of them according to the array length? Is it possible to use for-loop sentence inside the JasperSoft Expression Editor? ([if-then-else seems to be available](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/expressions))

Thanks in advance, Any clue that point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: `Is it possible to use for-loop sentence` - What is for-loop sentence in JasperReports?

Comment: Some expression that allows me to define a self-incremental variable to access the array items from beginning to end like `get(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone was in the same situation as I was, I must say this whole approach was wrong.

It's not about making a simple query which returns big block of complex data formatted as an object or list of objects and then manipulate it with JasperSoft Studio. Instead, what I had to do was design a more elaborated query which returns the simple fields I wanted to use straightforward. How to do this? By using Aggregation Framework.

So, by changing this...

```
{
    collectionName:'projectA',
    findQuery: {
        '_id':'clientsInfo',
    },
    findFields: {
        '_id':0,
        'data.clientsList':1
    },
}
```

...for this...

```
{
    runCommand: {
    aggregate : 'projectA',
    pipeline : [
        {'$match': {'_id':'clientsInfo'}},
        {'$project': {'data.clientsList': 1}},
        {'$unwind': '$data'},
        {'$unwind': '$data.clientsList'}
        ]
    }
}
```

...is how I get `name` and `country` fields in order to use them in Text Fields, Tables, ...etc.